# How to achieve following design in html

Tags: html, css

Please find following screenshot 
How to convert it into html

For More Clear understanding
**- The design should be responsive** 
**- Icons should animate when hover on the Icon** 
**- How Place Icons in those positions**

If background image i can achieve this but i need make it into html elements

[image]

Comment: (ᾥhat's that for a question?) Please elaborate and explain if your circles/graph are Elements or a background image, if it should be responsive, if you're talking about text alignment around elements or anything. Also show all your code that you've tried so far explaining your exact issue. otherwise your question does not fit the needed Q&A format for this site. *For more info:* [help]

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question is way too vague and nobody is going to your projects. If you want to have an answer, at least have a HTML code or something. Or, if you don't know HTML, go to Google and google "HTML tutorials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert this image to HTML you can use different methods. But I would definitely use an SVG image.

To do that:

- You can create an SVG image on illustrator/sketch or a similar software
- Then you can separate different elements by layers and give each layer a name
- export the SVG and open it with a code editor. You will notice that each layer has an ID
- Now you can animate each ID with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Hmm depends on what you see as html.
The dots and lines image can be added as background image with css but when the text gets increases it will overlap the images, if you want to make the image bigger when the text increases it's a lot more complicated.

Comment: Those circles are icons

Comment: So? You can still combine everything as one big image and use it as background image. It's just gets way more complicated when you want to make each icon a seperate html element that can be clicked on.

Comment: I need to achieve some animation when hover on those icons

Comment: Then it's quite a bit more complicated, you can make it a vector image as bg or use multiple html elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the `<canvas>` element.  You can draw circles and lines into it as you please.  The text rendering tends to be "not so good" (to say the least), so you may want to make *that* part of it a bitmap.  For the rest, drawCircle and moveTo/lineTo should suffice. (um, and arc for the ellipse)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```css
    #content {
        width: 664px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    heading {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: larger;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    article  {
        margin: 10px 100px;
    }
    
    #frame {
        z-index: 0;
        width: 664px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
         <div id="content">
          <heading>Title</heading>
          <article>
           <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                    since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                    scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
                    five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                    remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
          </article>
         </div>
         <div id="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" /></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Note that I re-saved your image as a PNG with a transparent background (instead of white), and I used 644 pixels as the width of **#content** and **#frame** only because that happens to be how wide the image is. Change to reflect the actual width of your full-resolution image.